# Найти систему счисления в которой предсавленная дробь будет конечным числом

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Допустим есть дробь 1/3 или 0.333... минимальная система счисления в которой она будет представлена как конечное число - это 3 (0.1).
Пример номер 2 3/4 - база 2 (0.11)

Можете скинуть алгоритм или тему в которой объясняется принцип нахождения данной базы

Comment: Где формулировка вопроса? Если в заголовке, то почему в тексте вдруг упоминается какая-то "минимальность"?

Answer (score 2):

Для дроби, заданной в виде m/n (натуральная дробь) минимальным основанием системы счисления, в которой эта дробь имеет конечную запись, аналогичную десятичной дроби (т.е. в виде 0.abcd, где a, b, c, d - цифры этой системы счисления), будет произведение всех простых делителей числа n.

Answer (score 0):

А в каком виде задана дробь?

Тут можно использовать алгоритм перевода дробного числа в новую систему счисления p: Умножаем на p пока не получим в дробной части 0, либо повторится дробная часть, либо получим нужное число знаков. Наш вариант это получить 0 в дробной части. Следовательно надо найти число x, что `x*(дробь)=k` - натуральное число.

Пусть задана несократимая  обыкновенная дробь `m/n`.

Рассмотрим два случая:

1. `n=p^k`, степень натурального числа тогда ответ p
2. n не является степенью натурального числа, тогда ответ n

Если дробь задана в виде периодической дроби, например `0,(3)`, то нужно представить в виде обыкновенной дроби.
Здесь http://math-prosto.ru/?page=pages/circulating_decimal/circulating_decimal.php написано как это сделать.

Если дробь задана в виде 0.2442, то она конечная.